# Node.js spellcheck

Tags: node.js, spell-checking

I have a Node.js application where user can enter value in a text box and submit. I want to add a spellchecker pop-up where user can correct any wrong spelling in the textbox (similar to what we have in outlook during sending emails). What could be a good tool to add with Node.js?

Answer (score 1):

Browsers already have spellcheck enabled by default for textarea DOM elements.

There are projects for typeahead functionality if that is what you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, but with browser spell check I can ignore those errors whereas here I want to enforce user to go through their errors and then submit the data.